# In Jquery on click function is not working for img in IE 6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, click, image

I tried to bind click and animate function on a img tag. Its works fine in firefox. but went wrong with IE. So i simplified the code and tested only for click . Even click function is not clled. Here is my click function for my img tag with class 'arrowimg'.

```
$('.arrowimg').click(function(){alert("Show me")});
```

I get this alert in FF but not in IE what might be the problem?

EDIT:here is my HTML generated code for img tag

```
<img src='http://localhost/gowri/Project/SS4U/public/images/symbols/advartise_right_arrow_NEW.gif' id="next" class="arrowimg" alt="advartise_right_arrow" />
```

Comment: is it inside `$(document).ready(function(){  })`?

Comment: yes i have the code inside document ready!

Comment: Can you post the html markup of the `<img>`? Does other javascript work well (eg, `alert(1);`)?

Comment: Even though IE should work with events on an image, did you try wrapping the image in an `<a>` or `<span>`, then binding a click function to it?

Comment: yes i could get the alert on document ready.
here is my code for the img tag
<div id="nextdiv"><img src="<?php echo _SS4U_SYM."advartise_right_arrow_NEW.gif"; ?>" id="next" class="arrowimg" alt="advartise_right_arrow"/></div>

Comment: Goysar, have updated my answer for you - let me know if that helps.

Comment: Well, you should have another space on the end for ie6: `<img ..." />` , but I doubt that's the problem. Can you post the generated html, not the php script? Try adding it to the question.

Comment: Is that the HTML that's generated in IE, Firefox or both?

Comment: @GenericTypeTea both FF and IE generated the same html code of that img tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure it's in the document ready event and then you end the alert with a semi colon.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.arrowimg').click(function(){alert("Show me");});
});
```

**EDIT**: Looks like there's something up with your markup:

You've got double quotes around 'advartise_right_arrow_NEW.gif'.

Should it be this instead:

```
<div id="nextdiv">
    <img src="<?php echo _SS4U_SYM.'advartise_right_arrow_NEW.gif'; ?>" 
        id="next" class="arrowimg" alt="advartise_right_arrow"/>
</div>
```

Comment: yes i have the code inside document ready!and even after adding semi colon to the alert it is not getting displayed.

Comment: @kobi sorry i cant get you. which function part. what poor?

Comment: I tried by changing the double quotes into single quotes still no improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, IE6 should be able to handle this. Make sure that you're getting any matches at all for your selector

```
alert($('.arrowimg').length);
```

If not, there may be something else that have gone wrong at an earlier stage.

Comment: yes i get the response it  matches to two img elements i have used in that page

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('.arrowimg').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   alert("Show me");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the future reference: **Check your jQuery version and your jQuery syntax**.

Using jQuery 1.6 and

```
 $('#elem_id').on('click', function(){ });
```

will **not** working because of **on** function. Error: **'undefined' is not a function**

Use

```
 $('#elem_id').click(function(){ });
```

instead or upgrade to a newer jQuery version. https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery